# How to upload image to django app by using request and json

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I wan to use some code for uploading some data to my django app. Im using this code:

```
r = requests.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/object/',
    json=data,
)
```

It's working great.

I have just added image (model.ImageField) to my model and I want to use above code to update it.

I still have some problem with encoding my image.

Im trying to read image and add to my previous dict with some data (data is dict with a few fields):

```
with open('image.JPG', 'rb') as imageFile:
    my_image = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read()).decode()
data.update({"image":my_image})
```

I got the same error:
"The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Is it possible to convert image to format which will be ok with request and json?

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: file and data together cannot be transferred as JSON unless you base64 convert the image which will significantly increase the size of the payload.

Comment: I don't care about the size to be honest ^^